# Marketing Cloud Triggered Send issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

We're implementing Triggered Send functionality for real time email roll out in MC. We have also written AMPScript in email templates to fetch values from a custom object. As Triggered Send can work only with Contact and Lead objects, we're using AMPScript to dynamically fetch values from custom object records.

We have a DE (Data Extension) used to store records with Subscriber relationship as *Subscriber Key relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key*.

While we are doing this, we're facing a issue during email send. While testing using "Generate Preview" button, "Subscriber Key" is getting changed to "Email Address" and MC throwing error. We've no idea why MC is changing subscriber id as email id.

Can someone help me out here, as this is a critical requirement am working on.

Comment: I assume you are using the AMPscript `RetrieveSalesforceObjects()` function. Please can you provide a snippet of the AMPscript code you are using?

Comment: Hey @EliotHarper,  thanks for the response. Yes we are using the method which you mentioned. We got rid of that error now. It was due to an AMPSCRIPT error in a 'IF' loop.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps you can answer your own question then and mark it as accepted, so that this open question can be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the AMPSCRIPT error in MC email template. Its fixed now.